# How to get the file path of active mouse cursor icon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, 2d-games, win32gui

I'm trying to get the cursor state name *or* the mouse icon file path while running a game. (The mouse icon is specific to the game)

I use python and win32gui and win32api.
I get the cursor handle with:

```
cursor_handle = GetCursorInfo()[1]
```

But this value is dynamic and changes every time I restart the game.
So, I've tried to work with memory addresses, but the static address found with the cheat engine is specific to the computer where my program is running. So now, I want to do something more autonomous.

To avoid these limitations, I would like to get the filename or the file path of icon associated with the current cursor_handle for a given position.

My first researches lead me to compare it to constant values known in the MSDN API

```
from win32con import IDC_APPSTARTING, IDC_ARROW, IDC_CROSS, IDC_HAND, \
IDC_HELP, IDC_IBEAM, IDC_ICON, IDC_NO, IDC_SIZE, IDC_SIZEALL, \
IDC_SIZENESW, IDC_SIZENS, IDC_SIZENWSE, IDC_SIZEWE, IDC_UPARROW, IDC_WAIT, \
IDI_APPLICATION, IDI_ASTERISK, IDI_EXCLAMATION, IDI_HAND, IDI_QUESTION, IDI_WINLOGO
```

But I didn't get any matches.

Any idea?

- I've tried to get the bitmap bits of the cursor icon. A null bitmap is returned when specific game icons are active. So no chances to identify them this way.
- News: the custom mouse cursor is generated by adobe flash Actionscript. After checking the mouse AS mouse API, to use a custom cursor, the mouse cursor needs to disable that's why I get a blank bitmap.